# Como redirecionar usuário após login de acordo com o nivel de usuário?

Tags: php, mysql

no sistema existem 2 niveis de usuários 1 = admin e 2 = auxiliar, e após fazer o login preciso redirecionar cada um para uma pagina diferente. Esse é meu código php

```html
<?php

session_start();
include('conexao.php');

if (empty($_POST['usuario']) || empty($_POST['senha'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
$senha = $usuario = $user_tipo = "";

$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['usuario']);
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['senha']);
$nivel = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['nivel']);


$query = "select nome, usuario, nivel from usuario where usuario = '{$usuario}' and senha = md5('{$senha}')";

$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$redirecionamentos = [
    '1' => 'usuarios.php',
    '2' => 'downloads.php',
];
if (array_key_exists($_SESSION['nivel'], $redirecionamentos)) {
    header('Location: ' . $redirecionamentos[$_SESSION['nivel']], true, 302);
}
if ($row == 1) {
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    header($redirecionamentos);
    exit();
} else {
    $_SESSION['nao_autenticado'] = true;
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
```

E me retorna esse erro quando eu acesso

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não está funcionando? Qual foi a mensagem de erro? Quais são as últimas mensagens no arquivo de log do servidor?

Comment: Bom ele não esta autenticando e nem redirecionando o tipo de usuário para a pagina especifica,no log aparece esses erros[26-Dec-2018 13:56:18 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home1/xopen037/public_html/gob.logosassessoriaconsultoria.com.br/gobdowloads/conexao.php on line 8
[27-Dec-2018 12:41:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home1/xopen037/public_html/gob.logosassessoriaconsultoria.com.br/gobdowloads/conexao.php on line 8

Comment: Ou seja, a conexão com o banco de dados falhou. Verifique os dados de conexão e certifique-se que o servidor de banco de dados esteja ligado.

Comment: eu estou fazendo a edição no servidor local wampserver, não no servidor online

Answer (score -1):

apos o login ao invés de criar um link de redirecionamento direto, faz uma validação para redirecionamentos de cada nível de usuário ou seja:

```
$query = "select nome, usuario, nivel from usuario where usuario = '{$usuario}' and senha = md5('{$senha}')";
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

faz a validaçao

```
if($row > 0) {
  if($linha['nivel'] == 1) {
    header("Location: redireciona-nivel-1.php"); 
  }
else if($linha[nivel] == 2) {
header("Location: redireciona-nivel-2.php"); // e assim sucessivamente...
}
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Jefferson pelo help, mas as paginas redirecionadas deve ter qual codigo de função? pois eu estou usando esse daqui
// Verificador de sessão 
session_start();
include('verifica_login.php');
?>
Só que não esta autenticando, mas quando eu coloco uma pagina do tipo redireciona-nivel-1.php (desconhecida) acaba redirecionando

Comment: e o codigo do verifica_login.php esta <?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
if(!$_SESSION['usuario']) {
 header('Location: index.php');
 exit();
}

Comment: Na pagina de restriçao faz uma validaçao por cada nivel por exemplo: if( isset($_session 'usuario ) empty($_session 'usuario' )) { //Vai verificar se a sessao existe //entao aplica aqui a validaçao por nivel 

if($linha_sessao['nivel'] == 1) { 
     Conteudo do nivel 1 
}
else {
redireciona para o login ou o conteudo q vc quiser
}

 }